# How to look between a section of HTML code using Beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How do I look within a specific section of HTML code using the Beautiful Soup package in python?

For example, I can convert the soup object into a string and separate the string into the section of HTML code I want to look within:

```
mystr= str(soup)  
str1 = mystr[mystr.find(', GENERAL</span><br/>'):]
str2 = str1.split('<caption align="Left">', 1)[0]

print(str2)
```

I would like to do the same procedure, but be able to keep the HTML code as a soup object.

Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert the string object of the desired section back into a soup object

```
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(str2, "html.parser")
```